# Load values into vue.js router guard before it is called

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am setting up a vue.js router guard in my main.js file. 
But i have a list of entitlements that needs to be passed into that router guard. 
I am fetching the needed entitlement list into the store in my App.vue created method - but i think it is too late for the router guard. 
My entitlement list is not available to the guard at the time it is initialized. 
Where can i load the entitlements so they will be ready for the guard when it needs them?

```
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
     entitledBeforeEach(to, from, next, store.getters.ENTITLEMENTS); });
```

that getter will always return null because main.js has not fetched the entitlements yet.
How can i do that sooner?

Comment: I think i may have gotten this to work by calling dispatch from within main.js between the store creation and the router guard init.

Comment: You could check if `ENTITLEMENTS` exists in a guard, and if they don't dispatch and await for finish, and then proceed your check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store, use an `action` instead of a `getter`.  The actions can be `async`, and should resolve once your entitlements are loaded or reused from a previous request.

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.dispatch('getEntitlements').then(entitlements => {
     // Do your processing and setup here.
     // There are many ways to get the entitlements into your component...
     next();
  });
```

Comment: this is basically what i wound up with. expect that i dispatch for the entitlements in an await before the router guard is setup

Comment: i'm making an assumption that i hope is valid - if the entitlements are mutated after the initial guard setup then the newest entitlements will always be used (the guard will get anew each route navigation)

Comment: Yes.  If your action makes another call to the server, `next` will not be called until it returns.  If your action returns cached data, it will return route immediately.  If you store your data (calling `commit` from `action`) and access it directly via getter in components, the getters will be reactive too at that point.  You can event have a timer that polls and updates with needing a route request.